# Wordpress Speed up page on mobile

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, mobile, pagespeed

I noticed that my page/onlineshop seems to load quite slowly on mobile. I already optimized anything I could in the past and always get a 95-100 lighthouse score on desktop which is great I guess. Still I cant manage to get it above 60-70 on mobile and I think thats too slow?

Unfortunately I'm not very experienced and have absolutely no idea where the problem is located. I would be very very thankful if someone could take a look and maybe give me at least a direction where I should focus on.

https://gesundbaumarktshop.de/produkt/auro-gartenmoebeloel-nr-102/ for example but basically any product has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend you reduce all your website image. that will help alot

Answer (score 0):

Overall, your page size is fine. Lighthouse is also not the end all be all for testing and I tend to use 2-3 services to test speeds.

However, CDNs may make a huge difference along with server side caching.

[image]

If you are able to, I'd recommend running your DNS through Cloudflare. They actually have a plan specifically for WordPress that is $5 USD roughly a month?